# Git merge conflict resolution: reverse order of (current & incoming change)

Tags: visual-studio-code, merge, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

Doing a `git merge master` on a branch, and conflicts are usually displayed in a file as follows:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

=======

>>>>>>> master
```

In Visual studio, you get an option to `Accept Current Change | Accept Incoming Change | Accept Both Changes`.

Now I want to accept both changes, however, they are in the wrong order. If only the master's change was first, then they would be in the right order and I wouldn't need to move things around.

Have many such conflicts and looking to see if I can somehow display the master's change above HEAD's, and thus enable a quick `Accept Both Changes` resolution.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Git itself has no way to do this (other than to run the merge the other way, i.e., to merge your branch into master, rather than the other way around, but that would be counterproductive in the end). Git leaves the rest of the work to your editor or other merge tool.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're using Visual Studio Code instead of Visual Studio. If that's the case please update the tag. The way you resolve conflicts in Visual Studio is different from Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I just wrote a regex to search and replace these occurrences with the desired resolution.